# How to embed additional code in link_to

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, link-to

I'm trying to embed additional code in a link_to but not sure how to get it to work. How do I go about doing that? I'm trying to get this to work:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("Favorite 3.png", class: "act_actions", title: "Unfavorite", alt: "Unfavorite") + <%= activity.votes.size %>, favorite_activity_path(activity), method: :put, :remote => true, :class => "btn favorite" %>
```

Comment: can you describe a little better what you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to use `linkt_to` as block to gain readability

```
<%= link_to favorite_activity_path(activity), method: :put, :remote => true, :class => "btn favorite" do %>
  <%= image_tag("Favorite 3.png", class: "act_actions", title: "Unfavorite", alt: "Unfavorite") %>
  <%= activity.votes.size %>,
<% end %>
```

I hope that the above code works for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way also.

```
<%= link_to "#{image_tag('Favorite 3.png', class: 'act_actions', title: 'Unfavorite', alt: 'Unfavorite')} #{activity.votes.size}".html_safe, favorite_activity_path(activity), method: :put, :remote => true, :class => "btn favorite" %>
```